# Coxeter notation for the symmetries of the maximally symmetric unit-distance embedding of $K_{3,3}$ in $\mathbb R^4$

Tags: group-theory, geometry, representation-theory, symmetry, coxeter-groups

My [Shibuya](https://github.com/Parcly-Taxel/Shibuya) repository now contains unit-distance embeddings in the plane of all cubic symmetric graphs to $120$ vertices, except the first two ($K_4$ and $K_{3,3}$) which do not have this property, as well as some not-so-symmetric cubic graphs (e.g. the McGee graph from [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1484002/357390) and the [Gray graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GrayGraph.html)) and a non-degenerate [Holt graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holt_graph).

[image: Unit-distance Foster, Holt and Gray graphs]

While I was making these embeddings (most of them via a semi-automatic program in Shibuya) I had [a 2018 paper by Frankl, Kupavskii and Swanepoel](https://arxiv.org/abs/1802.03092) in mind, which says that any connected graph with maximum degree $d$ can be unit-distance embedded in $\mathbb R^d$ – **except $K_{3,3}$**.

$K_4$ is obviously unit-distance embeddable in $\mathbb R^3$ with the maximum possible symmetry of $S_4$ – all automorphisms of the graph are symmetries of the embedding. That made me wonder if $K_{3,3}$ could be unit-distance embedded in $\mathbb R^4$ with *its* maximum symmetry of $(S_3×S_3)\rtimes C_2$. It is not too hard to find one (each vertex on the left is connected to all on the right), and indeed generalising this construction shows that all graphs with chromatic number $k$ may be embedded into $\mathbb R^{2k}$:
$$\frac1{\sqrt2}(1,0,0,0)\qquad\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,0,1,0)\\
\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1/2,\sqrt3/2,0,0)\qquad\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,0,-1/2,\sqrt3/2)\\
\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1/2,-\sqrt3/2,0,0)\qquad\frac1{\sqrt2}(0,0,-1/2,-\sqrt3/2)$$
This embedding's symmetries are generated by the following orthogonal matrices:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&-1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\qquad\begin{bmatrix}
-1/2&\sqrt3/2&0&0\\
\sqrt3/2&1/2&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\qquad\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&-1
\end{bmatrix}\qquad\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&0&-1/2&\sqrt3/2\\
0&0&\sqrt3/2&1/2
\end{bmatrix}\qquad\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
0&1&0&0
\end{bmatrix}$$
But having read about [Coxeter notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_notation) for point groups in arbitrary dimensions, I'm having trouble representing the above symmetries as a subgroup of a Coxeter group. Without the last matrix this would be $[3]\times[3]$ or $[3,2,3]$, but this last matrix has determinant $+1$ and I can't "fold" it into the other four matrices to make a rank-$4$ group of *only reflections*.

> How can the symmetry group generated by all five of the above matrices be written in Coxeter notation in the shortest possible way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conway and Smith's *On Quaternions and Octonions* contains a listing of all four-dimensional point groups, treating vectors in $\mathbb R^4$ as quaternions. For odd $n$ consider the following embedding of $K_{n,n}$, which when $n=3$ is equivalent to the embedding of $K_{3,3}$ in question after an axis swap and a scaling. Each point obtained from $f=i^n$ ("ring A", blue in the picture below) is connected to every point obtained from $f=j$ ("ring B", orange):
$$\{e^{2im\pi/n}f:0\le m<n,f\in\{i^n,j\}\}$$

[image]

Then the embedding's symmetry group has **no Coxeter notation** but is denoted in Conway & Smith as
$$+\frac14[D_{4n}×\overline D_{4n}]\cdot2_1$$
It is generated by the following $5$ quaternion operators:
$$[-e_n,1],[-1,e_n],[e_{2n},j],[j,e_{2n}],*[-1,1]$$
$$e_n=e^{i\pi/n},[l,r]:q\to\overline lqr,*[l,r]:q\to\overline l\overline qr$$
For $n=2p$ the embedding of $K_{n,n}$ is simpler in description:
$$\{e^{im\pi/p}f:0\le m<n,f\in\{1,j\}\}$$
Its symmetry group has Conway & Smith notation
$$\pm\frac12[\overline D_{4p}×\overline D_{4p}]\cdot2$$
with $11$ generators as follows:
$$[\pm e_p,1],[\pm j,1],[\pm1,e_p],[\pm1,j],[\pm e_n,e_n],*[1,1]$$